# How to change global navigation of a web page but not the site in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I created a web page with a custom page layout, the site the page is within has global navigation set to "Display the same navigation items as the parent site" and it was all good. I have now got the requirement to change the items in the global navigation for the page but keep the old setting for the site, how can I achieve this?

For a site I can go to site settings -> navigation and change the links as I like but the page is dependent on the site it is within. I don't have to start over and create a new site do I (instead of a simple page)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you do some kind of trickery (like Javascript embedded in the page) to do otherwise, the navigation settings are shared for all pages within the site.

If you wanted to *get rid* of global navigation for a particular page, you could customize your master page to put a special CSS class on the element wrapping it, and use some CSS inline on that page (ie. in a content editor webpart) to hide it.

Comment: I had to go with some trickery, added a script that does $("div[id$='TopNavigationMenuV4']").find('.static').replaceWith(allLinks); where allLinks is a HTML list I concatenated using the same classes as the original list so it looks the same.